# EF code first from C# returns error when trying to save byte[] to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to store an Accord.net teacher in SQL using EF. I have a model called TeacherModel:

```
public class TeacherModel
{
    public int TeacherModelId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

But I get an error as

type 'System.Byte[]' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.

I thought byte[] were accepted by default in SQL, so I am very confused by this message. Any help would be very helpful.

Comment: Entity Framework should map byte array to `varbinary(max)` by default. Which version of EF are you using? Also, please show your EF generated migration when you've introduced `Teacher` property first time.

Answer (score 0):

A type not being mapped in entity framework happens when there is no mapping to the property in the database. If you're using ef's code first, you need to do a migration and update your db context. If you are using an ado data model, you need to update the database and update the edmx.